# Is possible to make symlinks that 'follow' the file?

Tags: server, filesystem, command-line

Behavior:

```
me@local: tree
.
|-- ba
|   `-- file.txt
|-- foo
|   `-- file.txt -> ba/file.txt
`-- foobar
```

now, let's say i move the file.txt from `ba` to `foobar`:

```
me@local: mv ba/file.txt foobar/file.txt
```

I noticed that the symlink in foo folder still point the `ba/file.txt` path.

There is a way to create symlinks that auto-update the paths when the source file is moved?

Or symlinks that being deleted when i delete the source file?

Will be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create hard links.

Hard links have their own downsides, e.g., no links to directories, no links across file systems. And they're not deleted when you delete the "original"; in fact, they prevent the drive space for being freed, and you can still access the content through the hard link.

You can't create hard links in the file browser (Files, formerly Nautilus), but there's an old [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317268) (closed, won't fix) about it.

Comment: symlinks are the new kid on the block, and I think other operating systems that only allowed symlinks have caused people to never know that `ln` has been known to work without `-s` ;)

Comment: msw is right, for some reason not using `-s` with `ln` scared me for a while, I never thought it was appropriate to do.  In reality, it's not an issue unless you have crazy partitioning schemes and move files across them alot.

Comment: I don't think hardlinks actually do either of the things you asked? They don't "auto-update the paths when the source file is moved", and they don't get "deleted when i delete the source file".

Comment: @Ben: yes they do what i need, if i move a file hard links follow it

Comment: Personally, I think hardlinks are a bad idea in the general case. I found a lot of pitfalls to using hardlinks and I'm finding more every day. See http://superuser.com/questions/402295/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-hardlinked-files-on-my-desktop-pc

Comment: There is [a new bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1725) asking to add support for hard links

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with the normal linux filesystems as far as I'm aware.

Symlinks are really just a dumb bit of text that says "look, I'm really called Foo" - there's no checking that Foo exists, as you've found out. You can make symlinks that point to nothing with the same ease you can make symlinks that point to something useful.

Maybe someone with more knowledge of filesystems other than ext2/3/4 (like, say, jfs? or zfs? or zfs?) might be able to say if this is possible under more advanced filesystems than ext2/3/4. Maybe NTFS might support this even? NTFS doesn't have symlinks as such, but there is a similar feature called [Junction Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can.**

In the shell, you must type:

```
ln ba/file.txt foo/file.txt
```

this is a strong link, and if you even delete the file in ba/file.txt, it remains in foo/file.txt (you can see how many links there are with `ls -l` command

If you want to do what you did (create a symbolic link), you must type:

```
ln -s ba/file.txt foo/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

write a script or program to add an xattr to a file, to tell it the path to a symlink that points to it. then write a wrapper script for utilities you use (eg, mv) to update the symlink's target when the source file is moved.

Although I'm only half joking and this is a feasible solution, there are so many wall cases (as opposed to a corner or edge case...) that is sure to cause a lot of headaches (eg, moving the file with any other program).